# How to check the high level query in SpringBoot Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the code with multiple POJO's which carries the relationship of each model with each other i.e:

```
class A{

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
  private List<B> bList;
   
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
  private List<C> cList;


  //getter & setter
}
```

When I apply joins in hibernate/jpa using springboot , it executes multiple query(whether or not it is required) which is sometimes hard to read & understand (as class contains many relationships) because hibernate internally executes it with multiple alias . So is it possible to just get the finalized query i.e after the hibernate is done with all the queries execution we directly get the lastly formed query and not all the queries in between.

Thanks

Comment: Short answer no.

Comment: What do you mean by "the queries in between"? If Hibernate needs/uses multiple queries to load an entity there is no single "lastly formed query".

Comment: In logs you can see all queries generated by Hibernate and sent to DB. There are no any queries between, before or after. Of course you can improve some parts of this process (i.e.: N+1 problem) but that's a completely different story